# Show the Button in asp.net whenever the query execution occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using asp.net with c# and my aspx code is shown below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">
<table><tr><td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label></td></tr>

 <tr> <td>
   <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" BackColor="#993300" 
       ForeColor="White" onclick="btnsubmit_Click" /></td>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnlogout" runat="server" Text="Logout" BackColor="#993300" 
       ForeColor="White" onclick="btnlogout_Click"  />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now This is my c# code

```
cmd.CommandText = "update TrackingFaculty_det SET Type=@Type WHERE (FID=@FID) and DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60";
```

Which is present in submit button,I need to display the submit button whenever the above query is true and executed or else i dont need to show the submit button

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type = "c";
    string FID = Session["FID"].ToString();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    //int str_diff = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Difference"]);
    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = *"update TrackingFaculty_det SET Type=@Type WHERE (FID=@FID) and DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60*";
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FID",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    cmd.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
    cmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = type;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

    Response.Redirect("~/Faculty/Personaldet.aspx");
}
protected void btnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(@"~\home.aspx");
}
```

[image]
This image should display only if `update TrackingFaculty_det SET Type=@Type WHERE (FID=@FID) and DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60"` is executed

Comment: you want to `hide/show - enable/disable`  your submit button depend on your query result

Comment: Exactly @Satindersingh i need to show them when the query is executed,FYI u can see that the query will execute once in 2 months from the present day.

Comment: you are firing query on same button this is not feasible, you need to fire query on page something like page load, get result and now depend on result set button property `enable=false/true`

Answer (score 0):

put your submit button process on form load event then add a condition if it is true then hide/disable btnsubmit

Comment: Look for @Satinder sing answer just put that in your  Page_Load event

Answer (score 0):

You are firing query on same button this is not feasible, you need to fire `select query` like

```
Select * from TrackingFaculty_det  where  FID=@FID and 
DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60
```

on something like page load it return true/false, get result and now depend on result set button property

```
Button1.Enabled = false; // make button as disable
Button1.Visible = false; // make button invisible
```